# How to «leave» Google Cloud Platform project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Some time ago I was invited to participate in one project on Google Cloud Platform. Right now, I'm no longer interested in participating and would like to «leave» the project. This is what I see (among others) on the IAM & Admin page:
[Member with Editor Role on IAM page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH8Y9.png)

My question is the following. How can I, having Editor Role, leave this project, so it would be no longer listed in My Projects section?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently the only way to do this is to contact one or more project owners (eg. via email) and request that they remove you. Users don't have the ability to revoke their own ACL.

A useful feature could be to have some automation of the request process. This feature hasn't been publicly requested, but you can do so by filing a submission on the [Google Cloud Platform issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues).

Answer (score 2):

At least as of May 2020, you can go to the "IAM & Admin" section, edit your permissions and then remove yourself.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. It says:

You need permissions for this action. 
Required permission(s): resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy

Answer (score 1):

One thing worth noting is that often it's not your specific e-mail that is in the IAMs for the project, but rather some group your account is part of.

You can see a list of [all groups you belong to](https://groups.google.com/my-groups), and if you have IAM read access, you can compare that to [the list of IAMs on the project](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam), then leave the group giving you access to it. Unfortunately for projects where you don't even have IAM view access, I'm not sure if there's a way to trace it.